# Knockout Mapping - render template foreach as they become available

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am currently using the knockout mapping plugin to apply bindings to a very large data set loaded through AJAX, while the view has a foreach template binding. This is working as intended, but the performance is very slow because it waits to process the entire dataset.

Is it possible to modify the mapping behavior to push each item to an observable array so that the DOM elements render as they become available, rather than pushing 100+ elements into the DOM simultaneously?

Comment: You can use server side paging.

Comment: Is the map the performance bottleneck, or the rendering.  If the rendering is the culprit then map to a temporary array and push each item individually to the observableArray.  But knockout will be doing a LOT more work, and it will take much longer to complete.  I suspect you have another issue with bindings.  
Can you post an example ?